# Change Spaces between Bootstrap Icons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

There is too much spacing between icons. How to make these tightly close?

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
                                <button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></button>
                                <button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></button>
                                <button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></button>
                                <button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the padding on the buttons which is spacing them out:

```
.btn-link {
  padding:0;
}
```

```css
.btn-link {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></button>
  <button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></button>
  <button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></button>
  <button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></button>
</div>
```

There's also a 2px border you can remove if needed.